# Backup stateful docker volume

Tags: docker, backup, docker-volume

There are many containers that'll attach to the docker socket, enumerate the volumes, and back up the contents, but how do I orchestrate this together with a container that may be in the middle of writing or presumes it has exclusive access to the file(s)?  I'm thinking of SQL Server or Minecraft or another stateful data store that may trickle data in periodically in unpredictable ways.  Is there a strategy for grabbing transactionally consistent data from a docker volume for backup?  Or is there a way to tell one container to pause / stop another container during the backup operation?